# Problems with comment box

Tags: wordpress

Using Wordpress 3.9 with Theme 2014

Whenever I enable comments on a page, the comments box appears with Info already in the box.  As I'm new, I probably did something to cause this but I'll be darned if I can figure it out. Check out the website at http://donavantwebsites.com/

Comments is enabled on the home page and as you can see, my name, email address and website are already filled in. I would prefer these to remain blank. I'm still learning about trackbacks and pingbacks but I can't see, so far, how this would effect my problem.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are logged in, wordpess will automatically fill it in. If you log out/login with as different user it will show that information. For example when I view the link you posted, I don't see any information filled it.

[image]